# Why it shows undefined when solving problems with Node.Js in HackerRank?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

```
function gridChallenge(grid) {
    let sortedRows = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < grid.length; i++){
        let sortedRow = grid[i].split('').sort().join('')
        sortedRows.push(sortedRow)

    }

    let columns = []
    let sortedColumns = columns.sort()
    for(let z = 0; z < sortedRows.length; z++){
        let column = sortedRows[z].split('')[0]
        columns.push(column)
    }

    if(columns === sortedColumns){
        console.log("YES")
    } else {
        console.log("NO")
    }
}
```

The code is working completely fine in the IDE and showing the expected output but when I tried to run the same code in HackerRank it is showing that the code is giving **undefined** as output. And I've also tried with other problems it is giving the same result.

***Link of the problem:***
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/one-week-preparation-kit-grid-challenge/problem?isFullScreen=true&h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=preparation-kits&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=one-week-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=one-week-day-four

Comment: Your *function* returns `undefined` because you haven't included any logic to return anything out of it. Assuming [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/grid-challenge/problem) is the problem you're trying to solve, the prompt explicitly mentions an expectation that the function will return a string `YES` or `NO` - simply logging that string will not suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HackerRank does not work on console output... technically it does, but in a different way than what you're thinking. HackerRank will have code that it executes. That code will call your `gridChallenge` function. Next, it will print the result of your function. That is what HackerRank accepts as the "solution."

In JavaScript, like any other programming language, you have a `return` keyword to pass a value from the function to the **caller of the function**. You made the common mistake of printing the solution rather than returning the value of the solution.

This might seem misleading because the problem clearly states that you must print `YES` or `NO` on separate lines... that must have been a mistake on their part because in the code editor, it provides a doc-comment clearly stating the contrary:

```js
/*
 * Complete the 'gridChallenge' function below.
 *
 * The function is expected to return a STRING.
 * The function accepts STRING_ARRAY grid as parameter.
 */

function gridChallenge(grid) {
    // Write your code here

}
```